# Following services are not running: proxy @ AWS -- after Laravel re-config

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have Laravel application which I learned to run both with `php artisan serve` and with local Apache.

Now I wish to run the same on Amazon Beanstalk.

I have created Beanstalk instance for PHP7. Then I went to Amazon Linux console and installed composer there. I think this was unneeded step.

Next I acrhived all my Laravel project with ZIP and uploaded it to AWS with web console. First I got `Forbidden` error

[image]

as said here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/php-laravel-tutorial.html

Then I fixed document root to `public/` as said below and now I have health state `severe` saying

```
Impaired services on all instances.
Following services are not running: proxy.
```

When I am opening site with browser, I see blank page.

How to see any logs in AWS to understand what is happening?

What cen be a reason? Project is self-contained, it uses SQLite database inside the codebase. When I was enabling this project on local machine, I was to enable multiple things in Apache and PHP.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It was the problem with ZIP file structure: it contained extra top directory inside. So, on AWS it was `/var/app/current/myappname` while should be just `/var/app/current`.

Comment: I'm getting the same error. How did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you install mbstring after creating the instance?

```
sudo yum install php70w-mbstring
```

If this isn't the problem, you can view Laravel log in storage/log/laravel.log and tell us what is there to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error due to Elastic Beanstalk config settings being incorrect, specifically, the Document root was incorrect and was seeing the `Following services are not running: proxy.` error in the event log.

Answer (score 0):

When generating the ZIP archive, be sure to generate it within the project folder. So when you open the zip file, you have the app folder, not another folder with the project name.